# NVDA is reading out table <caption> twice, any way to make it read only once?

Tags: html-table, accessibility, screen-readers, caption, nvda

I'm working on some simple tables and trying to make them accessible.

During testing, NVDA is reading the `caption` out twice, which is very annoying.  On the second pass through it says "caption" at a couple of seemingly random places as well, which makes it even more annoying.

Is there any way to force the `caption` to only be read once?

Here is the html:

```
<table>
    <caption>
        <h4>
            Skilled nursing facility care
            <sup aria-hidden="true">1</sup>
            <span class="sr-only">
                <em>footnote 1 begin</em>
                A benefit period begins on the first day you receive services as an inpatient in a hospital and ends after you have
                been out of the hospital and have not received skilled care in any other facility for 60 days in a row.
                <em>footnote 1 end</em>
            </span>
        </h4>
        <p>
            You must meet Medicare’s requirements including three inpatient hospital days, prior to entering a Medicare-approved skilled nursing facility within 30 days
        </p>
    </caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="cell-no-bkg"></th>
            <th scope="col">Medicare pays</th>
            <th scope="col">Plan pays</th>
            <th scope="col">You pay</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <ol aria-hidden="true">
                    <li>
                        A benefit period begins on the first day you receive services as an inpatient in a hospital and ends after you have
                        been out of the hospital and have not received skilled care in any other facility for 60 days in a row.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Notice: When your Medicare Part A hospital benefits are exhausted, the insurer stands in place of Medicare and will
                        pay whatever amount Medicare would have paid up to an additional 365 days as provided in the policy’s “core benefits.”
                        During this time, the hospital is prohibited from billing you for the balance based on any difference between its billed
                        charges and the amount Medicare would have paid.
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="th-in-body">
                <p>First 20 days</p>
            </th>
            <td>
                <p>All approved amounts</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>$0</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>
                    $0
                    <sup aria-hidden="true">1</sup>
                    <span class="sr-only">
                        <em>footnote 1 begin</em>
                        A benefit period begins on the first day you receive services as an inpatient in a hospital and ends after you have
                        been out of the hospital and have not received skilled care in any other facility for 60 days in a row.
                        <em>footnote 1 end</em>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="th-in-body">
                <p>21st through 100th day</p>
            </th>
            <td>
                <p>All but $200 per day</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>$0</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>
                    Up to $200
                    <sup aria-hidden="true">2</sup>
                    <span class="sr-only">
                        <em>footnote 2 begin</em>
                        Notice: When your Medicare Part A hospital benefits are exhausted, the insurer stands in place of Medicare and will
                        pay whatever amount Medicare would have paid up to an additional 365 days as provided in the policy’s “core benefits.”
                        During this time, the hospital is prohibited from billing you for the balance based on any difference between its billed
                        charges and the amount Medicare would have paid.
                        <em>footnote 2 end</em>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="th-in-body">
                <p>101st day and after</p>
            </th>
            <td>
                <p>$0</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>$0</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>All costs</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can create a fake caption and have it read out only once but I'm losing the semantics of a `caption` element here.

The following table is exactly the same as the one above except for:

The leading div (my fake caption).
`aria-describedby` on the table to tie it to my fake caption.
`aria-hidden` on the table `caption` element.

```
<div id="table1-caption" hidden>
    <h4>
        <em>this fake hidden caption will only read out once</em>
        Skilled nursing facility care
        <em>footnote 1 begin</em>
        A benefit period begins on the first day you receive services as an inpatient in a hospital and ends after you have
        been out of the hospital and have not received skilled care in any other facility for 60 days in a row.
        <em>footnote 1 end</em>
    </h4>
    <p>
        You must meet Medicare’s requirements including three inpatient hospital days, prior to entering a Medicare-approved skilled nursing facility within 30 days
    </p>
</div>
<table aria-describedby="table1-caption">
    <caption aria-hidden="true">
        <h4>
            Skilled nursing facility care
            <sup aria-hidden="true">1</sup>
            <span class="sr-only">
                <em>footnote 1 begin</em>
                A benefit period begins on the first day you receive services as an inpatient in a hospital and ends after you have
                been out of the hospital and have not received skilled care in any other facility for 60 days in a row.
                <em>footnote 1 end</em>
            </span>
        </h4>
        <p>
            You must meet Medicare’s requirements including three inpatient hospital days, prior to entering a Medicare-approved skilled nursing facility within 30 days
        </p>
    </caption>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="cell-no-bkg"></th>
            <th scope="col">Medicare pays</th>
            <th scope="col">Plan pays</th>
            <th scope="col">You pay</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <ol aria-hidden="true">
                    <li>
                        A benefit period begins on the first day you receive services as an inpatient in a hospital and ends after you have
                        been out of the hospital and have not received skilled care in any other facility for 60 days in a row.
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        Notice: When your Medicare Part A hospital benefits are exhausted, the insurer stands in place of Medicare and will
                        pay whatever amount Medicare would have paid up to an additional 365 days as provided in the policy’s “core benefits.”
                        During this time, the hospital is prohibited from billing you for the balance based on any difference between its billed
                        charges and the amount Medicare would have paid.
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="th-in-body">
                <p>First 20 days</p>
            </th>
            <td>
                <p>All approved amounts</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>$0</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>
                    $0
                    <sup aria-hidden="true">1</sup>
                    <span class="sr-only">
                        <em>footnote 1 begin</em>
                        A benefit period begins on the first day you receive services as an inpatient in a hospital and ends after you have
                        been out of the hospital and have not received skilled care in any other facility for 60 days in a row.
                        <em>footnote 1 end</em>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="th-in-body">
                <p>21st through 100th day</p>
            </th>
            <td>
                <p>All but $200 per day</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>$0</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>
                    Up to $200
                    <sup aria-hidden="true">2</sup>
                    <span class="sr-only">
                        <em>footnote 2 begin</em>
                        Notice: When your Medicare Part A hospital benefits are exhausted, the insurer stands in place of Medicare and will
                        pay whatever amount Medicare would have paid up to an additional 365 days as provided in the policy’s “core benefits.”
                        During this time, the hospital is prohibited from billing you for the balance based on any difference between its billed
                        charges and the amount Medicare would have paid.
                        <em>footnote 2 end</em>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="th-in-body">
                <p>101st day and after</p>
            </th>
            <td>
                <p>$0</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>$0</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>All costs</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

What's the proper thing to do here regarding the caption being read out twice where the caption is not a simple text label but has some text behind it, both in a footnote and a description?  Using the native `caption` element seems to be a pretty poor experience in NVDA.

Comment: Is it still being read twice if you remove the `<h4>` from it?

Comment: Did it really work with your second `aria-describedby`? A table needs a _name_ (not a _description_), which is usually provided by means of the `caption`. [ARIA provides an example for a long-form description](https://w3c.github.io/aria/#example-6) as in your case, which refers to the name only in the table. The name of a table being repeated while navigating inside might be standard behaviour of NVDA. In that case you shouldn’t mess with it, but provide a short name.

Comment: @Andy, yeah, NVDA reads out the caption twice if you just have simple plain text in that.  That was probably the first thing I tried.

Comment: @Andy, yes, the second example with `aria-describedby` actually works well in NVDA (it only reads the caption once).  I tried adding a short name and description for the table via `<table aria-labelledby="name" aria-describedby="desc">` and it read it out twice as well. It reads the describedby before the labelledby, which seems backwards.  It seems like such a mess for something so simple.

Comment: The `<caption>` indeed plays the role of an heading, a label or a description for the table. So probably that as soon as you add an `<h4>`, or an aria-labelledby that references the same `<caption>`, then it will be read twice. I recommend to keep the content of `<caption>` short.

Comment: The caption being read twice has been [a bug in NVDA](https://github.com/nvaccess/nvda/issues/8735) for 5 years now. Perhaps add a comment to the bug to see if anyone is listening.

Comment: @slugolicious thanks for that link, very good to know.  So it's probably safe to assume jaws and voice over would read the caption only once?

Comment: @QuentinC the caption gets read 2x even if I reduce it down to small simple plain text.  I think that was actually the first thing I tried.

Comment: Well, OK, that's maybe a bug then, as pointed by @Slugolicious. Since in this case you can't do anything anyway, note that it's much less annoying to have a short text repeated twice than a long text. IF the bug hasn't been solved entirely after 5 years, that's maybe because it isn't so problematic in general. The NVDA community is quite active, so if it were really problematic, it would have been solved much sooner.

Comment: In any case, a caption for a table isn't supposed to be long. Remember that the caption text is read when landing on the table by pressing T, but also can become a choice in a navigation menu (some extensions propose a list of links, a list of form fields, a list of tables, etc. to navigate quickly; Jaws provide that by default). With a long text, the function loses its efficiency.